# Getting TypeScript error on Shippable but not locally

Tags: angular, typescript, shippable-ci

I have an Angular/TypeScript application that uses Shippable CI/CD. Everything works great normally but now getting a TS error on Shippable, but not when building locally. (same angular, node, and TS versions both locally and shippable)

The error is

> ERROR in src/search.component.ts(81,23): error TS2352: Type
>   'DataGroup' cannot be converted to type 'DataGroup[]'.   Property
>   'includes' is missing in type 'DataGroup'.
>   src/search.component.ts(83,27): error TS2352: Type 'DataGroup' cannot
>   be converted to type 'DataGroup[]'.

The offending lines are

```
dataGroups = _.chain(dataGroups)
  .filter(dataGroup => !metaDataGroupNames.includes(dataGroup.spreadsheetId))
  .sortBy('spreadsheetId')
  .value();
metaDataGroups = _.chain(dataGroups)
  .filter(dataGroup => metaDataGroupNames.includes(dataGroup.spreadsheetId))
  .sortBy('spreadsheetId')
  .value();
```

In the above, dataGroups and metaDataGroups are type DataGroup[]... and filter+sort does indeed return the same.

```
dataGroups: Array<DataGroup>;
metaDataGroups: Array<DataGroup>;
```

I tried to cast the result from value with `...value() as DataGroup[];` to no avail.

I also tried to throw everything on a single line like the below incase that was the issue, also to no avail.

```
this.dataGroups = _.chain(dataGroups).filter(dataGroup => !metaDataGroupNames.includes(dataGroup.spreadsheetId)).sortBy('spreadsheetId').value() as DataGroup[];

this.metaDataGroups = _.chain(dataGroups).filter(dataGroup => metaDataGroupNames.includes(dataGroup.spreadsheetId)).sortBy('spreadsheetId').value() as DataGroup[];
```

**update/workaround**

So I never figured out the actual issue but I just broke out the underscore operations into their own statements and the problem went away. Still weird how I was getting the TS error on shippable but not locally, and that it wasn't an error in the first place.

```
this.dataGroups = _.filter(dataGroups, dataGroup => !metaDataGroupNames.includes(dataGroup.spreadsheetId));
this.dataGroups = _.sortBy(dataGroups, 'spreadsheetId');
this.metaDataGroups = _.filter(dataGroups, dataGroup => metaDataGroupNames.includes(dataGroup.spreadsheetId));
this.metaDataGroups = _.sortBy(dataGroups, 'spreadsheetId');
```

Comment: hi, where is your ```metaDataGroupNames``` variable and wich type has?

Comment: @rcoro hey just added to my question, `dataGroups: Array<DataGroup>;`

Comment: where is your ```metaDataGroupNames``` declared?

Comment: @rcoro they are both the same, `metaDataGroups: Array<DataGroup>;`

Comment: i posted an aswer using ```some``` instead ```ìncludes``` in the filter function

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe You could use something like this, I changed the implementation using `some` instead `includes`:

```js
const metaDataGroupNames = [ { spreadsheetId:1, name:'one' }, { spreadsheetId:2, name:'two'}];

const dataGroups = [{spreadsheetId:1, name:'one'},{spreadsheetId:3,name:'three'}];

const filtered = dataGroups.filter(item => metaDataGroupNames.some(y => y.spreadsheetId == item.spreadsheetId));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: yeah that's fine I ended up just not using underscore's chain, but it doesn't actually resolve the issue of why I'm getting the error in the first place